# optimizing the for loop for faster performance

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization

I have a dataframe that contains the similarity scores 100x100 for each 100 products against 100 products(data_neighbours). I have another dataframe that has the data at user and product level(1000x100). I want to go through each product for each user and get top10 similar products from data_neighbours and their corresponding similarity scores and compute a function getScore as below:

```
def getScore(history, similarities):
   return sum(history*similarities)/sum(similarities)

for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
        user = data_sims.index[i]
        product = data_sims.columns[j]

        if data.ix[i][j] == 1:
            data_sims.ix[i][j] = 0
        else:
            product_top_names = data_neighbours.ix[product][1:10]
            product_top_sims = data_ibs.ix[product].order(ascending=False)[1:10]
            user_purchases = data_germany.ix[user,product_top_names]

            data_sims.ix[i][j] = getScore(user_purchases,product_top_sims)
```

How can I optimize this loop for faster processing. The example has been cited from here: `http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/collaborative-filtering-with-python/`

Sample data:
Data:(1000x101) user is the 101th column:

```
Index   user    song1   song2.....
0        1       0       0
1        33      0       1
2        42      1       0
3        51      0       0
```

data_ibs(similarity scores)--(100x100):

```
    song1   song2   song3   song4
song1   1.00    0.00    0.02    0.05
song2   0.00    1.00    0.05    0.03
song3   0.02    0.05    1.00    0.11
song4   0.05    0.03    0.11    1.00
```

data_neighbours(top10 similar songs for each song based on sorted score from data_ibs)--(100x10):

```
          1       2      3......... 10
song1   song5   song10  song4
song2   song8   song11  song5
song3   song9   song12  song10
```

data germany(user level data for each song as column, except userid)--(1000x100):

```
index   song1   song2   song3
1        0        0     0
2        1        0     0
3        0        0     1
```

Expected dataset(data_sims)--1000x101:

```
user    song1   song2   song3
1      0.00     0.00    0.22
33     0.09     0.00    0.11
42     0.00     0.10    0.00
51     0.09     0.09    0.00
```

where if value is 1 in data for any song, basically its score is set to 0, other cases, top 10 songs are fetched from data_neighbours and corresponding scores from data_ibs. Now it is checked if those songs are already present for the user or not(1,0) in user_purchases dataset. finally similarity scores are computed for the ixj position using user_purchses(1/0 values for each top 10 song) multiply by similarity score from data_ibs and divide by the sum of total top 10 similarity scores. Repeat the same for all the user x song combination.

Comment: If you have your data in `DataFrames`, looping should be your absolute last resort.

Comment: but it is really slow. Is there a way to utilize the vectorized operation for faster performance. Especially when I will encounter millions of records.

Comment: You just want the 10 largest values from your 100x100 dataframe along each axis? I'm pretty sure it can be done without iterating, have a go!

Comment: @muni, can you post a sample data set (5-7 columns, 5-7 rows) and a desired data set in __text/CSV/TSV/JSON/dict__ form?

Comment: added the sample datasets